# MySQL AES_ENCRYPT/AES_DECRYPT with Emojis

Tags: mysql, node.js

How do I encrypt and decrypt emojis using the MySQL function AES_ENCRYPT and AES_DECRYPT ()?

`req.body.txtMessage = form data such as 'Ok '`

The encrypted data is being stored in the database as a `varbinary(512)`.

```
AES_ENCRYPT('" + req.body.txtMessage + "', MD5('WnXX56ENr4tEMRM" + req.session.userID + "'))
```

```
CAST(AES_DECRYPT(`msg`, MD5(CONCAT('WnXX56ENr4tEMRM', `author`))) AS CHAR(50))
```

The decrypted output would then be put on the webpage using:

`$('#messages').html(res.output);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix. I had to set my NODE.JS database connection charset to use `utf8mb4`:

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'HOST',
    user: 'USER',
    password: 'PASS',
    database: 'DATABASE',
    charset : 'utf8mb4'
});
```